# Is it a sin to ask "gifted" people for help?

Tags: practical-islam, sin, spirituality

My brother knows a girl who claims to be gifted, she says she can read people's spirits and talk to them. I have been going through a tough time recently, and my brother knows so out of curiosity he asked her about me. She didn't know what I was going through other than the fact that I have been really upset lately. She said a lot of things about my "spirit" that were eerily accurate. I thought that my brother was making it up, or he told her about my situation, but he didn't. The problem is that I'm a muslim. I was wondering if it is okay for me to ask this girl for more details, and ask her to help me. Would this be shirk or a sin?

Comment: It's **haram.** You can give [this](https://whatisquran.com/758-the-science-of-quackery-in-islamic-review-part-1.html), [this](https://whatisquran.com/762-quackery-science-in-islamic-review-part-2.html) and [this](https://whatisquran.com/674-none-knows-the-unseen-but-allah-the-exalted.html) a read. Btw Infidel here means Kufr (closing yourself from the truth), and Quackery means Soothsayer or Magician etc. ETC (sometimes translations can mess up, and u can see how they define the arabic words directly at the site). and Allah knows best.

Comment: I'm not accusing her of witchcraft or something tho, in my country ppl like these are  usually grouped with "Indigo". Someone said it's because their ancestors has something called "Khodam" (Djinn) and it's passed on to their descendants. Well whether she do witchcraft or she's just indigo, the ruling still applies. and Allah knows best.